# Difference between UseCookieAuthentication and UseIdentity?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In `ASP.NET Core` Startup in `Configure` method when you are configuring piplelines you can use `UseIdentity` from `ASP.NET Core Identity` or you can use `UseCookieAuthentication`. Both of them provide cookie based authentication.

I want to know what is their difference. Is `UseIdentity` uses `UseCookieAuthentication` internally? What are advantages and disadvantages of one over another?

Thanks for your explanations.

Answer (score 9):

From the docs which can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity).

Cookie Authentication Middleware:

> ASP.NET Core provides cookie middleware which serializes a user principal into an encrypted cookie and then, on subsequent requests, validates the cookie, recreates the principal and assigns it to the User property on HttpContext. If you want to provide your own login screens and user databases you can use the cookie middleware as a standalone feature.

Identity:

> ASP.NET Core Identity is a membership system which allows you to add login functionality to your application. Users can create an account and login with a user name and password or they can use an external login providers such as Facebook, Google, Microsoft Account, Twitter and more.

In short Identity builds on just local authentication and provides the ability to perform external authentication as well as baked in solutions for provisioning user accounts.

The pros and cons of each differ depending on your business and both have their own place which I find is usually determine on a case by case basis.

The inner workings for Identity can be found on the github page [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity).

Comment: My final goal is to have cookie authentication along side token (JWT Bearer) authentication at a same time. I guess it is easier to use cookie authentication rather than ASP.NET Identity. But I am not sure at all. It is my use case scenario.

Answer (score 3):

> Is UseIdentity uses UseCookieAuthentication internally?

[Yes.](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/078512dc9417881ad5d2e5418eb03c4931c89efa/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/BuilderExtensions.cs)

However, both UseIdentity and UseCookieAuthentication will be deprecated in Auth 2.0.

[UseIdentity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/c142085695dc636a5655e52eb8ad8d4b673f4e5d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/BuilderExtensions.cs)

[UseCookieAuthentication](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/99aa3bd35dd5fbe46a93eef8a2c8ab1f9fe8d05b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAppBuilderExtensions.cs)

`services.AddCookieAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthentication()` will be used instead.

**Important note:** Don't use UseCookieAuthentication, if you have UseIdentity. I mixed them together in a project. Claim-based authorization redirected user to LoginPage instead of AccessDenied page.